# Android Unit Testing not working for Android library project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jvm, android-testing

We are trying to introduce the [new Android Unit Testing Support](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) to our project.

For library project, it fails to find the src/main/java classes when running with gradlew.

Running the test from Android Studio works as expected.
Running the test with gradle in an app project works as expected.
Running the test with gradle in a library project fails.

I created a sample project on [github](https://github.com/keesvandieren/AndroidJvmJunitTestSpike), that reproduces the problem in a small project.

With gradle plugin definition `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` it works fine, with plugin definition `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` the error occurs.

The error is:

```
home/user/path/AndroidJvmJunitTestSpike/common/src/test/java/squins/com/common/SomeClassTest.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    assertEquals(2, new SomeClass().sum(1, 1));
                        ^                    
  symbol:   class SomeClass                      
  location: class SomeClassTest                  
  /home/user/path/AndroidJvmJunitTestSpike/common/src/test/java/squins/com/common/SomeClassTest.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    new SomeClass().referenceDrawableFromR();
        ^                                    
  symbol:   class SomeClass                      
  location: class SomeClassTest                  
  2 errors                                         
  :common:compileDebugUnitTestJava FAILED
```

Is this supposed to work? Did I miss a thing?

Comment: You should flip around so that your packages looks like this: "com.squins.common" instead of "squins.com.common".

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! It was indeed wrong, Android studio asks for 'company domain' in new project wizard, which I interpreted as 'package name'.

Comment: @KeesvanDieren I think you should post this as answer. I have had this same issue. `gradlew clean assemble check`.

Comment: Just posted it as an answer. Its not optimal, but its better than nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround: trigger compilation manually. Gradle command that succeeds:

`./gradlew clean assembleDebug assembleRelease test`

Still looking for a better solution.